# Bash function seems to not want to correctly run lines

Tags: bash, shell-script, function

The question makes very little sense but lets get into it! I am working on a IRC Client in bash and I found some code and started adding it to an IRC bash bot code I have been working on. I have broken it down to simplify it.
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/user/bin/perl

function status_line() {
    echo -en '\e7' "\e[${status_line_row};0f" '\e[2K'
    echo -en "\e[4;44mSTATUS: $nick in $channel @ $channel\e[0m"
    echo -en '\e8'
}

function read_line() {
while true
do
    while read -r -t1
    do 
        status_line
        echo -en '\e[2K\r> '
        echo "PRIVMSG $channel :$REPLY" >> $input   
    done
done
}

. bot.properties
input=".bot.cfg"
echo "Starting session: $(date "+[%y:%m:%d %T]")">$log 
echo "NICK $nick" > $input 
echo "USER $user" >> $input
echo "JOIN $channel" >> $input

read_line | tail -f $input | openssl s_client -connect $server:6697
```

Upon running this and typing input into terminal it does correctly input and send $REPLY to IRC but it does not correctly do status_line and echo -en '\e[2K\r> ' inside read_line. I am confused why the input is being read but the 2 lines before it aren't working.
I ran bash -x on it to see this (below) after sending a msg to IRC and this doesn't even fix it without -x.

```
+ status_line
+ echo -en '\e7' '\e[;0f' '\e[2K'
+ echo -en '\e[4;44mSTATUS: Omen in #lair @ #lair\e[0m'
+ echo -en '\e8'
+ echo -en '\e[2K\r> '
+ read -r -t1
+ true
```

If you wish to see the full code it is here > https://pastebin.com/cHLiwZNf

Comment: It probably works if you remove the `tail -f`, right?

Comment: @Kusalananda Nope can not seem to even connect to the IRC if I remove `tail -f`. :/

Comment: Oh, I see now, your `read_line` writes to `$input`.  You will have to make everything write directly to `openssl`.  The issue is with buffering. I think Linux has some sort of `setbuf` command that may help (to turn _off_ buffering), but I'm currently unable to test.

Comment: You are using the wrong language for this job.  Shell is good at running and orchestrating other programs that do things.  It is not good at doing things itself.   In this case, you should use `expect` instead of `bash`.   Or, better yet, a language like perl or python which have expect-like libraries **AND** libraries with binding to openssl C library functions.

Comment: @Kusalananda,  you're thinking of [`stdbuf`](https://manpage.me/?q=stdbuf)

Comment: @glennjackman That's the one!

Comment: @Kusalananda, I don't know if you get the issue i'm having. I am having no issue sending my `$REPLY` from `read` into `$input`. The issue is `status_line` and `echo -en '\e[2K\r> '` are not being executed correctly in a sense. They appear to be called with `bash -x` but do not appear. This two things make a status line that doesn't allow for when the terminal reads a msg from the IRC channel to steal my input and drag it up with it and for the very bottom line where it reads input to start with '>' before the input.

Comment: Something to do with `echo -en` cause if I add `echo "..." >> $input` that works correctly and is sent to the IRC. It seems to not want to echo to the terminal even if its as simple as `echo "Hello World`".

Comment: "I am working on a IRC Client in bash" -- why would you do that..? instead of using an actual programming language, that is? Esp. since even an IRC client needs to be able to watch for input from both the user/terminal and the network connection at the same time, and for that, you need `select()` which I don't think even Bash provides.

Comment: @ilkkachu well why not is the question!!! I have it working well at the moment just configuring every msg to print to the terminal properly and even adding support for multiple channels! I love it when people ask me why haha cause no one else does. Thats my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
function read_line() {
    ...
    while read -r -t1; do
        status_line
        echo -en '\e[2K\r> '
        echo "PRIVMSG $channel :$REPLY" >> $input   
    ...
}

read_line | tail ...
```

> it does not correctly do status_line and echo -en '\e[2K\r> ' inside read_line. I am confused why the input is being read but the 2 lines before it aren't working.

Inside `read_line`, you read from stdin with `read`, and you print to stdout with `echo`. (And also to `$input` with the other `echo`, but that's not a problem.)

Noting how you're calling the `read_line` function as part of the pipeline, consider where the stdin and stdout of `read_line` are connected? What does the pipeline do to the input and output streams of the commands involved? What does `tail` do with its stdin?

---

Also note that if that `>` is supposed to be a prompt for the user, it should probably be printed *before* the `read` call, not after it. Either do `while echo -en '\e[2K\r> '; read -r -t1; do ...`, or use `read -p` to have it print a prompt instead. If the terminal is set up in the usual way, the screen will also scroll both when the user hits enter on the `read`, and when you print something. If the statusbar is at the top of the screen, it will scroll out of sight. You'll have to do something about that, and it's much easier with a pre-existing UI library like `ncurses` than fixing up the terminal processing by hand in the shell.

Another problem with an IRC client is that it *needs* to be able to read from two places at the same time: both input from the user, and data from the network. Fixing the output from `openssl` back to the script for processing is somewhat awkward in itself, and having to read both at the same time is worse.

The real solution to that is to use [the `select()` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) (or `poll()`). Even though Bash provides access to network sockets via the `/dev/tcp` pseudo-files, I don't think it provides `select()`.

So, really, there's two big reasons there to use an *actual programming language* and **not the shell** for this.

Of course, if you're only doing this as an exercise in insanity, then that's fine, but if so, I suggest getting a bit more familiar with the shell language first before tacking a problem like this. Also, if you just want to have fun with programming in a limited environment without any real-world significance, I could suggest a few games from [Zachtronics](https://www.zachtronics.com/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kusalananda, their answer sent me searching and I found the answer. If the answer they gave was right thanks again anyways sorry lol! Anyways adding `>&2` at the end of lines I wanted to be printed to the terminal! Still working with it and making it right for my case but it works!!

```
function read_line() {
while true
do
    while read -r -t1 REPLY
    do 
        echo 'Hello World' >&2
        echo -en '\e[2K\r> ' >&2
        echo "PRIVMSG $channel :$REPLY" >> $input   
    done
done
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First, there's a lot to unpack here. If you haven't started using [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), then you should start - it makes life much easier by highlighting defects on writes.

Second, the shell does NOT like this line: `echo -en '\e7' "\e[${status_line_row};0f" '\e[2K'`. I'm not sure what it's supposed to do but it causes the cursor to jump up one line and write a blank(?); that can't be what you're after. Fix this first.

Next, within the context of this block, the `while true` bit seems like you don't need it.

```
function read_line() {
while true; do <- unnecessary
    while read -r -t1
    do 
        status_line
        echo -en '\e[2K\r> '
        echo "PRIVMSG $channel :$REPLY" >> $input   
    done
done <- unnecessary
}

# This should do exactly the same thing but you have to feed the loop
while read -r -t1; do 
    status_line
    echo -en '\e[2K\r> '
    echo "PRIVMSG $channel :$REPLY" >> $input   
done < /from/file, or
done <<< "$fromVariable" (pick one from file or variable)
```

Lastly, here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/todd-dsm/7c6303e2f039bbe8046cbeb613e7b1a8) that should help to outline how colorize output much easier. I call it as a library and reuse over multiple scripts. PS: I hate the solution but it works.

Comment: Why would the shell "not like" that `echo -en '\e7' ...` command? The quotes are fine, giving multiple arguments to `echo` is fine. With `-e`, the `\e` gets turned to the ESC character, and it prints three different terminal control commands. (namely, save cursor position, move cursor, and erase line. In combination with the rest of the function it makes sense, the only thing being that the spaces added by echo between the arguments move the cursor two spaces forward from the start of the column)